# How to reverse the git diff output for uncommitted changes?

Tags: git, git-diff

I have some uncommitted, unstaged changes which I want to create a patch from, but also flip the `+` and `-` lines.

`git diff` shows a change like:

```
-apple
+orange
```

I want it to be like

```
+apple
-orange
```

but without committing the changes and then using a `git diff commita..commitb`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git diff -R
```

[`-R`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--R) means "reverse".